# Flash sound doesn't work in most browsers

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, browser, audio

I'm trying to play sound from url.

```
var s : Sound = new Sound();
s.load(new URLRequest("http://85.21.236.228:8000"));
s.play();
```

It's OK in Opera browser. But in IE, Chrome, Firefox there's no any sound. Can anyone help me? Thanks.

Comment: Which flashplayer version are you targetting and which flashplayer version do you have in IE, Chrome, Firefox (they could be different)?

Comment: @Mark Knol I have 10,1,102,64 in IE, and 10,2,152,14 in others.

Comment: BTW, It's OK with local files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I've found the solution. URL should end with "/;". So,

```
s.load(new URLRequest("http://85.21.236.228:8000/;"));
```

this works.

Comment: This is not the solution.  Your problem is that you were trying to play the file immediately after calling load, but not waiting for the load to complete.  @www0z0k has your answer if it's a streaming sound.  Otherwise you would listen for Event.COMPLETE.  In either case, simply calling s.play() immediately after calling s.load isn't going to work in the end.

Comment: @scriptocalypse You're mistaken, it will play automatically, when loads. The idea is that i was trying to play radio stream and for some reason URL must end with "/;" for correct work in any browser

Answer (score 1):

try

```
sound = new Sound();
sound.addEventListener(Event.OPEN, onStart);
sound.load(new URLRequest(path));

private function onStart(e:Event):void {
    channel = sound.play();
}
```

btw does your link return an mp3 file?

Comment: This stream is unavailable now. BTW, I've found the solution :)